# Are if(0) and if(1) statements optimized?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, logging, compilation, c-preprocessor

For debugging purposes I wanted to have a preprocessor definition such as

```
#define LOGGING 1 //or #define LOGGING 0 when logging is undesired
```

and add

```
if (LOGGING) log("Text here!");
```

wherever I want it to happen in the code.

Now, I only want to do this if the compiler is able to read

```
if (0) log("blah blah blah");
```

for example, and simply not add this to the final code. And alternatively if the *if* is set to true

```
if (1) log("blah blah blah");
```

erase the *if* conditioning and only add the line.

So, in the end, do those *if*s actually affect performance?

PS: I am using VS, but can also use g++

Comment: It depends on the compiler, but likely yes, branches that cannot be reached are optimized away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any decent compiler should optimize away an `if` statement with a hard coded value. However, if you're already going down that line, why not do it all with the preprocessor?

```
#ifdef LOGGING
#define LOG(message)     printf(message);
#else
#define LOG(message)
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (0)` and `if (1)` are optimized away by all *popular* compilers if optimization setting is turned on.

But in any case, these checks are very lightweight and would not noticeably affect performance even if they would make it into compiled binaries.

---

Considering readability, I would suggest removing `if`s from code and using preprocessor to strip away `log()` if logging is turned off:

```
#if !defined(LOGGING)
  #define log(message)
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

With VS in release mode it's optimized.

You can check verify yourself in the assembler code (go on project properties, C++, output files and choose assembler with source code.

In debug mode,  the code generated is not optimized and looks like:

```
; 14   :    if (0) 
    xor eax, eax    
    je  SHORT $LN2@test            <<<<<<<<< conditional test 
; 15   :        log("blah blah blah");
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_0P@KFNJKNNG@blah?5blah?5blah?$AA@
    call    ?log@@YAXPAD@Z              ; call log
    add esp, 4
$LN2@test:
    ...                             << followed by the standard return sequence 
    ret 0
```

In release mode, it's:

```
; 14   :    if (0) 
; 15   :        log("blah blah blah");
; 16   : }
    ret 0                           << nothing:  he returns
```